# Как вытащить значение из поля ввода?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть input, в нем на карточке товара есть поле для ввода количества товара. Есть вспархивающее сообщение. Как во вспыхивающем сообщении вывести количество товара, указанное в поле input? Хотелось бы сделать все на javascript.

Comment: Поэтично-то как... Внезапно выскочила таблица, испуганно вспорхнули сообщения, от неожиданности выбило ошибку...

Comment: Стараемся.
а если серьезно, это ява скрипт стоит.
"кривые пальцы" называется

Answer (score 2):

Если по простому, то дать инпуту ИД и по нему обращаться:

```
document.getElementById("count").value
```

Comment: а потом выводить как?

данный синтаксис встречал. примерно понимаю как обращаться к нему.

Comment: и получится ли так же обратиться по имени инпута


т.е



document.getElementByName("products_qty").value

Comment: `getElementById` - слишком сложно как для `input`'a :)

Лучше ведь присвоить ему `name` и обращатся по нему:

    count.value

Comment: getElementById всегда возвращает или о или 1 элемент, а вот getElementByName возвращает массив, поэтому там ещё 


    document.getElementByName("products_qty")[0].value

Comment: +1 к ответу, рукалицо к комментам

Comment: Пробую так - не выводится.

`function () {
    var QTY = document.getElementByName("products_qty")[0].value;
    document.write('<span> ' + QTY + ' </span>');
}`

я наверное где-то в синтаксисе косячу. да?

Comment: @Palmervan я не прав с getElementByName?

Comment: @KoVaLsKy забыл s в имени функции

    getElementsByName

Comment: поставил. все равно не реагирует.
я правильно понимаю что по идее  на месте данного скрипта, если я все правильно сделаю то должно вывестись значение из инпута?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5Fvnu/

Comment: А как бы теперь вывести в тексте эту фишку.

Comment: Дайте ваш код, надо смотреть

Comment: alert("Сообщение");

Answer (score 0):

Как сказал [[@Nord001](/users/6627/nord001)](/users/6627/nord001)

```
var txt=document.getElementById("count").value
```

можно получить значение инпута а вывести можно по простому без дизайна:

```
alert("Сообщение: "+txt);
```

а можно по сложному:

```
function closef(){
    var oldwind=document.getElementById("infowind");
    document.body.removeChild(oldwind,true)
}
function windOpen(txt){
    var wind=document.createElement("div");
    wind.class="window";
    wind.id="infowind";
    var clsbut=document.createElement("div");
    clsbut.onclick=closef;
    clsbut.class="clsbut";
    var textar=document.createElement("div");
    textar.class="textar";
    textar.innerHTML=txt;
    wind.appendChild(textar);
    wind.appendChild(clsbut);
    document.body.appendChild(wind);
}
```

и CSS:

```
#window{
 //Стили блока окна
}
#clsbut{
 //Стили кнопки
}
#txtar{
 //Стили текстового поля окна
}
```

Открывать можно так: `windOpen(txt);`

Answer (score 0):

Если не устраивает функция getElementById, то действительно можно обращаться по именам:

```
window.alert('value: '+document.form_name.input_name.value);
```

Comment: вообщем у меня одним
onclick=

с его помощью див со свойством display:none;
появляется.
т.е по сути мне нужно что бы я в одном месте сайта вводил в инпуты что то и на этой же стрнице в другом месте появлялись эти же значения

Comment: <div id="buttonwindopen" onclick="document.getElementById('fwind').style.display='block';" >
</div>
<div id="fwind">
содержимое окна.
сюда то и хотелось бы вывести количество
</div>

Comment: как бы нашел решение, но

var a=(document.getElementsByName("products_qty")[0].value);
document.write(a);

как сделать что бы обновлялось значение переменной А постоянно. а не при перезагрузке страницы